# Translating a short sentence to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I want to translate the following sentence to Latin:

> 'And this concludes our journey.'

Here 'this' refers to the preceding text. The sentence could be paraphrased as, 'And this is the end of our journey.'
My best try is the following but I will need your help as I have only recently started learning Latin again.

> Et hic iter nostrum concludit.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Feedback on your translation

While *concludere* is obviously etymologically related to the English "conclude", it does not quite mean the same thing.
It can mean "end" in the sense you want, but it also means things like "compress", "confine", or "shut up".
In most use cases context would provide the correct meaning, so this is not a major issue.

The only real problem is the pronoun *hic*.
It is masculine, so it refers to some singular masculine thing you previously described.
If you want a general "it" for a thing, use the neuter instead.
In Latin you can also use the plural neuter where English would use singular, and this is particularly advisable if you refer to a number of things.

### Suggested translations

I would translate concluding here using *finiri* (lit. "to be ended") or *finem capere* (lit. "to take an end").
My first reaction is to go with

1. *Sic finitur iter nostrum.* (So ends our journey.)

or

2. *Talem capit finem iter nostrum.* (Our journey takes such an end.)

Whether these are appropriate depends on what "this" is and whether you want it to have agency in the ending of the journey.
If you mean "this sequence of events causes the journey to come to a conclusion" rather than "so ends our journey" (as I took it), then I would suggest simply

3. *Hoc finit iter nostrum.* (This ends our journey.)

You can also replace *hoc* with the relative pronoun *quod*.
In Latin you can start an independent sentence with a relative pronoun referring to what was just mentioned.
This is far less idiomatic in English.
So perhaps this would work nicely:

4. *Quod finit iter nostrum.* (This ends our journey.)

Suggestion 3/4 is active whereas 1 is passive with the same verb.
You can add an *et* in the beginning of your sentence for "and".
Whether such a connective would be needed in Latin depends on context, but in general I have no major objections.
However, I would not add it when using a relative pronoun.

If you want to make "this" plural, you could go:

5. *Haec/Quae finiunt iter nostrum.* (This [= these things] ends our journey.)

### Unrelated remark

I was somewhat shocked to read your profile text describing your aspiration to study theoretical physics to help merge QFT with GR.
I had a *very* similar mindset as a starting student, although after a master's degree in theoretical physics I got my doctorate in math and shifted to a more mathematical view on physics for most of my work.
I just couldn't help pointing out that I'm glad to see people here who share other passions than Latin with me.
Welcome to the site!

Comment: So, in Latin you don't use 'concludere' in the same sense as in English? As in, when you finish a text/speech/lecture and you end the last remark with 'And this concludes today's lecture'? And thank you for the warm welcome! I should update my site, though. My focus has shifted to QCD. I am finishing my master's degree at the moment. Who knows what comes next?

Comment: @ThomasWening It can mean the same as in English, but that is only one of the many meanings it has. [This dictionary entry gives an idea of the variety of meanings.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=concludo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)

Comment: I did my master's thesis on QFT and neutrino physics, but then a surprising offer came along and went after something else after graduation. Having a plan for research in physics was important for my career trajectory even though it never came true in a form I could anticipate. My research interests still cover QCD, QFT, and especially GR, but from a different angle.

Comment: Let me heartily endorse your answer (5), *Quae [verba] finiunt iter nostrum*. *Verba* is, in my opinion, redundant, but redundancy is only rarely a reason to reject a word. Plus if the final sentence actually contains a neuter plural, then *quae finiunt iter nostrum* might, in that unusual case, actually be ambiguous.