# Latin Translation of “This is how it ends.”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I had this phrase pop into my head, and I would appreciate if I kind soul could translate it to Latin. It relates to the end of the world, so I will leave it to the translator to decide the best “flavor” of Latin to use (if that even makes sense)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14134/translating-a-short-sentence-to-latin

Comment: *Sic finit*. Thus it ends.

Answer (score 1):

If *it* is the world, in ecclesiastical Latin I propose

*Sic transit mundus*

which is similar to the well-known and oft-quoted *Sic transit gloria mundi* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic_transit_gloria_mundi) for sources)

In Latin, putting *sic* at the beginning of the sentence is enough to achieve the pragmatic effect of ”This is how it ends”, while English resorts to a somewhat more complex syntax.